# Compare different item in two file and output combined result to new file by using AWK

Tags: linux, tcp, awk

Greeting!

I have some file in pair taken from two nodes in network, and file has records about TCP segment send/receive time, IP id number, segment type,seq number and so on.

For same TCP flow, it looks like this on sender side:

```
1420862364.778332 50369 seq 17400:18848
1420862364.780798 50370 seq 18848:20296
1420862364.780810 50371 seq 20296:21744
....
```

or on receiver side(1 second delay, segment with IP id 50371 lost)

```
1420862364.778332 50369 seq 17400:18848
1420862364.780798 50370 seq 18848:20296
....
```

I want to compare IP identification number in two file and output to new one like this:

```
1420862364.778332 1420862365.778332 50369 seq 17400:18848 o
1420862364.780798 1420862365.780798 50370 seq 18848:20296 o
1420862364.780810 1420862365.780810 50371 seq 20296:21744 x
```

which has time of arrive on receiver side, and by comparing id field, when same value is not found in receiver sid(packet loss), an x will be added, otherwise o will be there.

I already have code like this,

```
awk 'ARGIND==1 {w[$2]=$1}
ARGIND==2 {
flag=0;
for(a in w)
    if($2==a) {
        flag=1;
        print $1,w[a],$2,$3,$4;
        break;
    }
if(!flag)
    print $1,"x",$2,$3,$4;
}' file2 file1 >file3
```

but it doesn't work in Linux, it stops right after I pressed Enter, and leave only empty file.

Shell script contains these code has been through chomd +x.

Please help. My code is not well organized, any new one liner will be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Isn't the id field unique enough for you? couldn't you just look for the missing id?

Comment: Why print the id number twice at the start of each line? `ARGIND` is gawk-specific btw so check your awk version.

Comment: Thank you Mr Ed Morton, I installed gawk and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`ARGIND` is gawk-specific btw so check your awk version. –  Ed Morton